# Windows cannot open the zip file

Tags: windows, zip, corruption

I am trying to integrate Face Book in my Android App. When I downloaded the Face Book SDK, and open it, It shows the message, Windows can not open zip file. Its invalid. How can I solve that problem?

Kindly help me.

I am downloading the package from this URL: 
https://developers.facebook.com/android/

The error message is showing in the pix below.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `.zip` file is corrupted. Try downloading it again and see if this persists, but it surely shouldn't be tagged "Android", "Facebook" etc. This  looks clearly like a "Windows" problem to me.

Comment: i tried it many times @g00dy ;(

Comment: Do you have WinZip or WinRar ?

Comment: Anyway if you do, you canit open the file (considering it's corrupted) unless you use a repair program such as:
http://www.download.com/Zip-Repair/3000-2250_4-10624972.html?tag=lst-0-2

Comment: Check this link as well ;) https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=8K16Nv3hWGYekc5m83Mfmg&cp=19&gs_id=21&xhr=t&q=the+compressed+zip+folder+is+invalid&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=the+compressed+zip+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48572450,d.Yms&fp=bfd4a4306d448a26&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=899&bs=1

Comment: I have WinZip. The problem is not with WinZip or WinRar.. My other files are opening :( ;(

Comment: Then again, the problem is in the file itself. Try finding the SDK on another code base like code.google.com or somewhere else. I'm telling you, either the download can not finish properly for some reason, or the file is corrupted (Which I doubt).

Comment: I have tried to many sites.:( Any way  thank u  :( ;( @g00dy

Comment: Well, try to repair the archive with a program, like the one I suggested: http://www.download.com/Zip-Repair/3000-2250_4-10624972.html?tag=lst-0-2 . I'vo no more suggestions though :(

Comment: Did the author of the question find the solution?

Comment: Sure, most probably the file was really corrupted, do you have the same problem?